# Writing NUL characters to csv

Tags: python-2.7, csv, data-integrity, nul

I am trying to preserve data integrity while writing to a csv file and am having trouble writing null characters. The following code snippet produces a file with `"Hello"`

```py
with open('outfile..txt', 'wb') as f:
    row = ['Hello\x00World']
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

I want to avoid replacing/removing null characters due to the nature of the data I am working with. `f.write()` works fine but I figure it will be a bit of a hassle writing my own class to handle quoting, escaping, and separating values. Are there any viable alternatives other than creating a custom csv writer?

Comment: Reproduced on Python 2.  Python 3 works correctly.  Switch?  Python 2 is EOL in 2020.

Comment: row = ['Hello\x00World'.encode('ascii')]

Comment: CSV files are intended for the storage of plain text (i.e. printable characters); any attempt at storing a binary value like `\x00` violates the format and cannot be expected to work (even if it does for some implementations)